# Django Custom Manager to dynamically filter archived objects

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

When I query on **Car**, I always want to return the objects satisfying, is_active=True.
For this, searching on StackOverFlow, I get that my best bet is to use **ModelManager**, like this:

```
class CarManager(models.ModelManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
```

And, use this **Manager** in my model.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = CarManager()
```

Using this solution always returns active **Car** queryset.
But, sometimes I want to return inactive **Car** queryset as well, and I don't want to write another **ModelManager**.

To elaborate,

1. When I run,

   Car.objects.all()
   or,

   Car.objects.filter(name__contains='Car')
   or,

   Car.objects.filter(is_active=True)

I only want active **Car** queryset.

2. When I run,

   Car.objects.filter(is_active=False)

I want to have inactive **Car** queryset.

And, I want to achieve this using single **ModelManager** and default methods (get, filter, all, etc). Why I want this is because, it has been used in many places already.

So, is there any way to achieve this? Any suggestions or insights are heartily welcome.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a long research and going through documentations and Django source code, I have come up with this for filter() method:

```
class CarManager(models.ModelManager):
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('is_active') == False:
            return super().get_queryset().filter(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.get_queryset().filter(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
```

Here, I have overriden filter() method, so that:

1. If **is_active=False** is passed, then the parent (default) get_queryset() followed by filter() is called.
2. If **is_active** is not passed or **is_active=True** is passed, then the overridden get_queryset() method is called (which returns the active Car queryset) followed by the filter() method.

If there are any other solutions or better practices, please do mention them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid is not possible since you are overwriting the manager's base queryset. What you could do instead of creating another manager is to implement an extra method that returns a queryset with only inactive cars, something like:

```
class CarManager(models.ModelManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)

    def get_inactive_cars(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=False)
```

And then replace the querysets where you retrieve the inactive ones:

```
Car.objects.get_inactive_cars()
```

Comment: Oh, is it not possible to use parameters of the query? Like, check if is_active is used in filter and return corresponding result?